# How do I make a script run at startup (not from settings)?

Tags: release-hera, startup

I need to make a script run at startup to launch an application. How do I do this outside of the GUI (outside of settings>applications>startup)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually add a .desktop file to ~/.config/autostart/ and this would be executed by elementary on login. This would be effectively identical to using the GUI though.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you.